# comma separate conversion in the input box Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

I have a input box (using C# razor) that user can input a string. I have use ToString("#,#0.00") to format as a numerical value since user will input a numerical value in the input box. When the user press enter it will calculates automatically for example 'average' and generate a percentage which it works. And it will updates the cell. The problem is that I want the input box to accept comma separated (e.g 2,000 or 30,000)in the input box. However, when I did some testing by trying to input numerical value with comma separator, 2,000 will become 2.00. Im trying to figuring out but I couldn't and i am stuck. Can you please help me. Thanks.

This is my html razor code ( I have post the partial code of it since too long):

```
<table>
  <tr class="header expand">
                                    <th class="dcf-left-column-border-table"><span class="sign"></span>Revenue</th>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-border-table"></td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-border-table"></td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-border-table"></td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[0].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[0].Sales.ToString(), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[1].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[1].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[2].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.HistoricalFinancialYears[2].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[0].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[0].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[1].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[1].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[2].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[2].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-middle-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[3].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[3].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                    <td class="dcf-right-column-bg-border-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[4].Sales, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedFinancialYears[4].Sales.ToString("#,#0.00"), new { @class = "dcf-input-box" })</td>
                                </tr>
<tr style="table-layout:auto">
                                <th class="dcf-average-title-table">Average</th>
                                <td class="dcf-average-values-table">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.objIncAppr.ProjectedAverageGrowthRate, Model.objIncAppr.ProjectedAverageGrowthRate.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), new { @class = "dcf-average-input-box" })</td>
                                <td class="dcf-ratio-title-table">Growth Rate</td>
                                <td id="dcf-ratio-values-table">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Input" list="growthrate" />
                                    <datalist id="growthrate">
                                        <option>BDO Benchmark</option>
                                        <option>Historical Benchmark</option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </td>

</table>
```

This is my scripts:

```
 <script>
        //#region Updated version for auto calculation Projection
        //hook the change event to the update method
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dcf-input-box').on('change', function () {
                $(this).UpdateGUI('green', true);
            });
            $('.dcf-ratio-input-box').on('change', function () {
                $(this).UpdateGUI('green', true);
            });
        });

        //RF: update a cell with new value and refresh the remaining cells in the same column
        //Note: the list of Account Names and list of element IDs have to be in the same order
        function updateCellWithNewValue(currAccount, newValue, listOfAccountNames, listOfElementIDs) {
            for (i = 0; i < listOfAccountNames.length; i++) {
                if (listOfAccountNames[i] === currAccount) {

                    //RF: update the current cell
                    result = parseFloat(newValue).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[i]).val(result);

                    //RF: refresh cells beneath the current cell
                    for (j = i + 1; j < listOfAccountNames.length; j++) {
                        updateCellByRefresh(listOfAccountNames[j], listOfAccountNames, listOfElementIDs)
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //RF: refresh a particular cell
        function updateCellByRefresh(currAccount, listOfAccountNames, listOfElementIDs) {
            switch (currAccount) // i.e. Sales
            {
                case "Gross Income":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iCOGS = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("COGS");
                    iGI = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Gross Income");

                    //RF: get curr Sales and COGS, then convert them to float datatype
                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrCOGS = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iCOGS]).val()) || 0;

                    //RF: calcuate the new gross income based on user changed sales and same curr COGS
                    var dblNewGI = dblCurrSales - dblCurrCOGS;

                    //EC: update the new gross income
                    result = parseFloat(dblNewGI).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iGI]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "Gross Income Margin":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iGI = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Gross Income");
                    iGIMargin = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Gross Income Margin");

                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrGI = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iGI]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewGIMargin = (dblCurrGI / dblCurrSales) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewGIMargin).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iGIMargin]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "EBITDA":
                    iGI = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Gross Income");
                    iSGAExp = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("SGAExp");
                    iEBITDA = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBITDA");

                    var dblCurrGI = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iGI]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrSGAExp = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSGAExp]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewEBITDA = dblCurrGI - dblCurrSGAExp;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewEBITDA).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iEBITDA]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "EBITDA Margin":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iEBITDA = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBITDA");
                    iEBITDAMargin = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBITDA Margin");

                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrEBITDA = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iEBITDA]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewEBITDAMargin = (dblCurrEBITDA / dblCurrSales) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewEBITDAMargin).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iEBITDAMargin]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "EBIT":
                    iEBITDA = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBITDA");
                    iDeprAmort = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("DeprAmort");
                    iEBIT = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBIT");

                    var dblCurrEBITDA = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iEBITDA]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrDeprAmort = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iDeprAmort]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewEBIT = dblCurrEBITDA - dblCurrDeprAmort;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewEBIT).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iEBIT]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "EBIT Margin":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iEBIT = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBIT");
                    iEBITMargin = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBIT Margin");

                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrEBIT = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iEBIT]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewEBITMargin = (dblCurrEBIT / dblCurrSales) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewEBITMargin).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iEBITMargin]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "Tax Rate":
                    iEBIT = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBIT");
                    iInterest = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Interest");
                    iTax = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Tax");
                    iTaxRate = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Tax Rate");

                    var dblCurrEBIT = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iEBIT]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrInterest = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iInterest]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrTax = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iTax]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewTaxRate = (dblCurrTax / (dblCurrEBIT - dblCurrInterest)) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewTaxRate).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iTaxRate]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "Net Income":
                    iEBIT = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("EBIT");
                    iIntetrest = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Interest");
                    iTax = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Tax");
                    iNetIncome = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Net Income");

                    var dblCurrEBIT = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iEBIT]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrInterest = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iInterest]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrTax = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iTax]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewNetIncome = dblCurrEBIT - dblCurrInterest - dblCurrTax;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewNetIncome).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iNetIncome]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "Net Income Margin":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iNetIncome = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Net Income");
                    iNetIncomeMargin = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Net Income Margin");

                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrNetIncome = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iNetIncome]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewNetIncomeMargin = (dblCurrNetIncome / dblCurrSales) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewNetIncomeMargin).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iNetIncomeMargin]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "DeprAmortFCFF":
                    iDeprAmort = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("DeprAmort");
                    iDeprAmortFCFF = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("DeprAmortFCFF");

                    var dblCurrDeprAmort = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iDeprAmort]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewDeprAmortFCFF = dblCurrDeprAmort

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewDeprAmortFCFF).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iDeprAmortFCFF]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "FCFF":
                    iNetIncome = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Net Income");
                    iDeprAmortFCFF = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("DeprAmortFCFF");
                    iCapEx = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("CapEx");
                    iNWC = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("NWC");
                    iFCFF = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("FCFF");

                    var dblCurrNetIncome = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iNetIncome]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrDeprAmortFCFF = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iDeprAmortFCFF]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrCapEx = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iCapEx]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrNWC = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iNWC]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewFCFF = dblCurrNetIncome + dblCurrDeprAmortFCFF - dblCurrCapEx - dblCurrNWC;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewFCFF).toFixed(2);
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iFCFF]).val(result);
                    break;

                case "FCFFMargin":
                    iSales = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("Sales");
                    iFCFF = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("FCFF");
                    iFCFFMargin = listOfAccountNames.indexOf("FCFFMargin");

                    var dblCurrSales = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iSales]).val()) || 0;
                    var dblCurrFCFF = parseFloat($(listOfElementIDs[iFCFF]).val()) || 0;

                    var dblNewFCFFMargin = (dblCurrFCFF / dblCurrSales) * 100;

                    result = parseFloat(dblNewFCFFMargin).toFixed(2) + " %";
                    $(listOfElementIDs[iFCFFMargin]).val(result);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        //RF: updates GUI based on user's input
        jQuery.fn.UpdateGUI = function ($paramColour, $paramIsBold) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var fontWeight = ($paramIsBold === true) ? "bold" : "normal";
                this.style.color = $paramColour; // colour font
                $(this).css({ "font-weight": fontWeight }); // bold font

                var currAccount; //i.e. Sales
                var currYr; //2

                var intAccBeg;
                var intAccEnd;
                var intYrBeg;
                var intYrEnd;
                var refPrefix;

                // get "Sales" from "objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_0__Sales" or "objIncAppr_HistoricalFinancialYears_0__Sales" of the id
                intAccBeg = this.id.indexOf("__") + 2;
                currAccount = this.id.substring(intAccBeg);


                //RF: get currYr (i.e. "0") from "objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_0__Sales" or "objIncAppr_HistoricalFinancialYears_0__Sales" of the id
                //RF: get refPrefix (i.e. "objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_") from "objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_0__Sales" of the id or "objIncAppr_HistoricalFinancialYears_" if it's a historical year)
                if (this.id.indexOf("objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_") > -1) {
                    intYrBeg = this.id.indexOf("objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_") + 35;
                    currYr = this.id.substring(intYrBeg);
                    intYrEnd = currYr.indexOf("__");
                    currYr = currYr.substring(0, intYrEnd);
                    refPrefix = "#objIncAppr_ProjectedFinancialYears_";
                }
                else {
                    intYrBeg = this.id.indexOf("objIncAppr_HistoricalFinancialYears_") + 36;
                    currYr = this.id.substring(intYrBeg);
                    intYrEnd = currYr.indexOf("__");
                    currYr = currYr.substring(0, intYrEnd);
                    refPrefix = "#objIncAppr_HistoricalFinancialYears_";
                }

                // get references (i.e. IDs) of all the required cells
                var refCurrSales = refPrefix + currYr + "__Sales";
                var refCurrCOGS = refPrefix + currYr + "__COGS";
                var refCurrGI = refPrefix + currYr + "__GrossIncome";
                var refCurrGIMargin = refPrefix + currYr + "__GrossIncomeMargin";
                var refCurrSGAExp = refPrefix + currYr + "__SGAExp";
                var refCurrEBITDA = refPrefix + currYr + "__EBITDA";
                var refCurrEBITDAMargin = refPrefix + currYr + "__EBITDAMargin";
                var refCurrDeprAmort = refPrefix + currYr + "__DeprAmort";
                var refCurrEBIT = refPrefix + currYr + "__EBIT";
                var refCurrEBITMargin = refPrefix + currYr + "__EBITMargin";
                var refCurrInterest = refPrefix + currYr + "__Interest";
                var refCurrTax = refPrefix + currYr + "__Tax";
                var refCurrTaxRate = refPrefix + currYr + "__TaxRate";
                var refCurrNetIncome = refPrefix + currYr + "__NetIncome";
                var refCurrNetIncomeMargin = refPrefix + currYr + "__NetIncomeMargin";
                var refCurrDeprAmortFCFF = refPrefix + currYr + "__DeprAmortFCFF";
                var refCurrCapEx = refPrefix + currYr + "__CapEx";
                var refCurrNWC = refPrefix + currYr + "__NWC";
                var refCurrFCFF = refPrefix + currYr + "__FCFF";
                var refCurrFCFFMargin = refPrefix + currYr + "__FCFFMargin";
                var refCurrDiscountYear = refPrefix + currYr + "__DiscountYear";
                var refCurrYearFrac = refPrefix + currYr + "__YearFrac";
                var refCurrDiscountFactor = refPrefix + currYr + "__DiscountFactor";
                var refCurrNPV = refPrefix + currYr + "__NPV";

                var listOfAccountNames = [
                    "Sales", "COGS", "Gross Income", "Gross Income Margin", "SGAExp", "EBITDA", "EBITDA Margin", "DeprAmort", "EBIT", "EBIT Margin", "Interest", "Tax", "Tax Rate", "Net Income", "Net Income Margin", "DeprAmortFCFF", "CapEx", "NWC", "FCFF", "FCFFMargin", "DiscountYear", "YearFrac", "DiscountFactor", "NPV"
                ];
                var listOfElementIDs = [
                    refCurrSales, refCurrCOGS, refCurrGI, refCurrGIMargin, refCurrSGAExp, refCurrEBITDA, refCurrEBITDAMargin, refCurrDeprAmort, refCurrEBIT, refCurrEBITMargin, refCurrInterest, refCurrTax, refCurrTaxRate, refCurrNetIncome, refCurrNetIncomeMargin, refCurrDeprAmortFCFF, refCurrCapEx, refCurrNWC, refCurrFCFF, refCurrFCFFMargin, refCurrDiscountYear, refCurrYearFrac, refCurrDiscountFactor, refCurrNPV
                ];

                var newValue = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
                updateCellWithNewValue(currAccount, newValue, listOfAccountNames, listOfElementIDs);

            });
        };
            //#endregion
    </script>
```

[image: I have enter 2,000 in the input box]
[image: After press enter it becomes 2.00 and not accept as 2000 in the calculation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it fixed. By using replace(/[^\d.]/g, "") which can format the numerical.

I modified this line of code:

```
var newValue = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")) || 0;
```